# Creating an array of 3D vectors where each element of each vector is from a given range

Tags: arrays, numpy, vector

I am trying to implement an array of 3D vectors. All vectors are combination of element ranges. What I mean is:

```
array = [v_1, v_2, v_3,....]

v_j = [x_1, x_2, x_3] with x_i in [a, b].
```

The important thing for me is, that I want to have all possible combinations.

So for example let a = 1, b = 10. Then it should be something like:

```
v_1 = [1, 1, 1], v_2 = [1, 1, 2],...v_10 = [1, 1, 10]
```

and then the next one should be:

```
v_11 = [1, 2, 1], v_12 = [1, 2, 2]....
```

I tried it by using linspace but I just get the vectors where each element is equal i.e.

```
v_1 = [1, 1, 1], v_2 = [2, 2, 2]....
```

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to do it by a lot of loops.

My linspace example was:

```py
ffac = np.linspace(-1E-3, 1E-3, 100, endpoint=True)

for i in range(100):
            eps = np.ones(shape=[100, ]) * ffac[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `a` and `b`, we can make `np.arange(a, b+1)`, and then use `np.meshgrid`:

```
xij = np.arange(a, b+1)
np.transpose(np.meshgrid(xij, xij, xij), (2,1,3,0))
```

For `b=2`, we obtain:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.meshgrid(xij, xij, xij), (2,1,3,0))
array([[[[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 2]],

        [[1, 2, 1],
         [1, 2, 2]]],

       [[[2, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 2]],

        [[2, 2, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]]]])
```

For a vector of *n* options, the result is thus a *n×n×n×3*.

Or if you want to flatten it:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.meshgrid(xij, xij, xij), (2,1,3,0)).reshape(-1, 3)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: So this is for a 3x1 vector. Is there an easy way to do the same for a 2x2 Matrix? Or even for a nxn matrix?